# Как задать директорию С++

Tags: c++, файлы

Мне нужно взаимодействовать с файлом `paroli_ot_vk_druzei.txt`.

Допустим, он находится по адресу `C:\papka\papka2\vzlompentagona\sekretnayapapka\paroli_ot_vk_druzei.txt`.

В свою очередь, моя программа находится в

`C:\proekt\nevirus.exe`.

Как работать с этим файлом (`paroli_ot_vk_druzei.txt`)?

Comment: указать путь - тут других вариантов (на сколько мне известно) нет. Единственное что хочу добавить: `getenv()` - функция, которая возвращает системную переменную. Это полезно, когда ваши каталоги находятся относительно каких-то системных переменных

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используя имя

```
C:\papka\papka2\vzlompentagona\sekretnayapapka\paroli_ot_vk_druzei.txt
```

Ну, или, если очень хочется -

```
..\papka\papka2\vzlompentagona\sekretnayapapka\paroli_ot_vk_druzei.txt
```